# Can't enlarge swap drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, swap

Running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Netbook.
Netbook has like .8 gigs of Ram so I'm trying to offset the crappy ram amount with a larger swap drive.

Tried to do it from a pretty detailed tutorial, was unable to add or expand swap drive.
Tried to Uninstall & reinstall Ubuntu and do it on initial installation but still could not get the swap drive to be any larger then 1061 mb

anybody have any idea why? or what I'm doing wrong?
you can go ahead and call me a noob, I'll agree with you, ha.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install Gparted either via the Ubuntu software center or via command line: `sudo apt-get install gparted`

The swap drive normally is a normal partition on your hard drive so you can use GParted to shrink a partition next to the swap partition and then enlarge the swap partition filling the free space.

Be warned that doing anything wrong or having a power loss while partitioning may lead to loss of data so backup your data if in doubt.

You can find further information about partitioning here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition